# Store react component names or another reference to an component in a variable (useState) without importing the entire API (i.e.@tabler/icons-react)

Tags: react-hooks, import, element

As an example, I've seen this before and it works to `import * from` an API and then down select to the required item at run time using the required name to select from entire API list (i.e. `IconHome`)

But when I look at the bundle.js download size from the developer options on the browser, it appears to increase by about 500kB, and we are trying to minimize bandwidth useage.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-darkness-i5tjy8

```js
import * as allIcons from '@tabler/icons-react';
const name = "IconHome"
const IconToBeUsed =  allIcons[name] 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <IconToBeUsed size={48} color="blue" />
    </>
  );
}
```

I would think it would be necessary to import the required components by name, either individual or if there a way to use the `import * from` with a pre-selected, smaller portion of the API. While this doesn't work, something like this

`import {IconHome, IconAdjustments} as someIcons from '@tabler/icons-react'`

and then it would be possible to use the above functionality on the smaller set of the API.

`const IconToBeUsed =  someIcons [name]`

otherwise, we will then have to just import each normally/individually

`import {IconHome, IconAdjustments} from '@tabler/icons-react'`

Which would be ok, but how then can I refer to that component without actually using the name directly...
something like these, which don't work

`const IconToBeUsed2 = React.createElement(name)`

`<{name} />`

Ultimately I would like to be able to store the icon name in an object, along with a few others and periodically modify their attributes (size, color) and when necessary change the icon for error states.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was closer than I thought. Not as elegant as I was hoping for... but it might be the best.

Import individual components then combine them into a single object of components and then down select them as you need.

```js
import {IconHome, IconAdjustments} from '@tabler/icons-react'
const someIcons = { IconHome, IconAdjustments };
const name = "IconHome";
const IconToBeUsed2 = someIcons[name]; 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <IconToBeUsed size={48} color="blue" />
      <IconToBeUsed2 size={48} color="red"/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Note if you are using typescript, you have to define what kind of index you are using

`const someIcons: {[index: string]:any} ={  IconHome, IconAdjustments}`

now you can store the name properly

`const name:string = "IconHome"`

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially only renaming your imported icons by creating that implicit object and later binding new `const`s pointing to its indiviual properties. Since the values are JSX components, you can use them in a `<YourCustomConstName />` fashion.

You could go the react way and create a component for this matter (here: `ReactiveIcon`) that stores its own current icon in a state and -- based on its props in a reactive manner -- changes that very icon to reflect current outer state.

```js
type ReactiveIconProps = {
  route: 'home' | 'settings'
  isError: boolean
} & IconProps


const ReactiveIcon = (props: ReactiveIconProps) => {
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState(IconHome)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isError) setIcon(IconExclamationCircle)
    else if (props.route === 'home') setIcon(IconHome)
    else if (props.route === 'settings') setIcon(IconAdjustments)
  }, [props.isError, props.route]

  const { route, isError, ...iconProps } = props
  return <icon {...iconProps} />
}
```

This example reacts to its `props.isError` and `props.route` values to derive any required change for the currently set icon and then just renders that current icon using the given icon properties.

You would use it like so:

```js
export default function App() {
  // Error state should be derived from some error boundary context
  const [isError, setError] = useState(false)
  // Current route is usually derived from router state
  const [route, setRoute] = useState<'home' | 'settings'>('home')

  return (
    <>
      <ReactiveIcon isError={isError} route={route} size={48} color="blue" />
    </>
  );
}
```

(Depending on router and error boundaries in your application, you should be able to derive the required states and either keep them in your parent component or pass them into the `ReactiveIcon` as they are)